# Elegant way to check whether external long-term jar launched successfully

Tags: java, exception, process, jar, exit-code

I am trying to execute external jar from java app.

**What is the most elegant way to check if the process has been started successfully and running?**

ExtApp.jar is long-term running process, so I can not use `Process.waiFor()` because it would block my app. I have come up with following code, with idea behind is that the `exitValue()` throws `IllegalThreadStateException` if the process has not been yet terminated.

```
boolean success = false;
try {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar ExtApp.jar");
    try {
        if (process.exitValue() == 0) 
            success = true;
    } catch (IllegalThreadStateException e) {
        success = true;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {}

System.out.println(success);
```

But it is kind of ugly solution. Any ideas for a better one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be no elegant solution to the problem. E.g. I ran your code on my PC and got "success" though there is no ExtApp.jar on it. That is, from the point of view  of Runtime.exec the process (java.exe) started successfully, no matter what happens afterwards.

Comment: You are right. There is a timing issue. If check the code with debugger and ExtApp.jar does not exist it shows `false`, if running not from debugger then it shows `true`.

Comment: Right, this is what I mean, timing, and timing is not elegant because you never know how long to wait before making a decision

Answer (score 2):

The above seems very dubious. You're going to spawn off your process and then test it immediately. The process itself may not have determined whether it's running ok or not (e.g. when does it actually check that jar file eixsts/is loadable/is valid ?)

I think you're better off spawning the process via a new thread, calling/blocking in that thread via `Process.waitFor()` and then notifying the parent thread (via whatever means - state variable, `wait()`/`notify()`, a `java.util.concurrent.Future` etc.) once the process has exited and you've collected the exit status.

[Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/) is a useful library for doing this sort of work, including asynchronous spawning/notification of process exit. See the [DefaultExecuteResultHandler](http://commons.apache.org/exec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/exec/DefaultExecuteResultHandler.html) for more info.

Comment: it is a long-term process, it would not exit.